# How to use inline assembly in C++ to set the Trap flag

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

How do we access the trap flag in x86 architecture and change its value in a 32 bit program?

I have tried using inline assembly in Visual Studio:

```
     #include <iostream>
      void trap() 
       {
          __asm PUSHF ;
          __asm MOV BP, SP;
          __asm AND WORD PTR[BP + 0], 0FEFFH;
          __asm POPF;
       }
```

and got the following errors:

```
error C2432:  illegal reference to 16-bit data in 'first operand'
error C2415:  improper operand type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a 32-bit program. Why are you trying to use 16-bit addresses? Your stack pointer is most likely larger than `0xffff`. You should instead

1. Do 32-bit `MOV` in the second assembly line to avoid losing higher bits of `ESP`,
2. Use 32-bit register to access the value you've pushed.

Moreover, there's no need to even clobber `EBP`: in 32-bit addressing mode you can directly access stack via `[ESP]`.

After taking all this into account your function will look as follows.

```
void trap() 
{
    __asm PUSHF ;
    __asm AND WORD PTR[ESP], 0FEFFH;
    __asm POPF;
}
```

Still, this code doesn't seem to make much sense: you'll get another trap after executing `pushf`, and the `and` instruction may never get executed.